# how to remotely shutdown the multiple computers in the LAN by qt5？

Tags: qt, shutdown, lan

i have a computer,i want to use my computer to shut down the rest of computer in the lab.so i need to write programs to implement this function with qt5;

That is：Remotely shutdown many computers in the same LAN.
i have all the computers' IP and name.
all the computers have the window7 OS;
can anyone help me write the qt5 codes for me?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you can install a server on these computers, you could make a TCPsocket client/server solution.

In the client application on your computer, you could connect to all other IP's
and send a shutdown message. On the server computers, when you receive the shutdown message, you could execute:
`QProcess::startDetached("shutdown.exe /s");`

But this could perhaps be an easier solution:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc770416.aspx
http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/windows7/windows7_shutdown_command.htm

Comment: thanks for your answer, i want to relize like this:  i can input several IP or names , then click the button "ok", these computers will shut down, I'm not familiar with TCPsocket ，I have not studied the knowledge about communication, so i don't understand the principle. i just study qt for 3 months.  i do not know whether it is easy to implement with QT？could you give me some codes ? thank you